# What does “dans trois semaines” mean?

Tags: sens, indications-de-temps

I just want to confirm the meaning of the following sentence:

> Les cours à l'université commencent dans trois semaines.

Does the above sentence mean that:

- The university courses will start in three weeks?

or

- The university courses will start in week three?

Comment: Please tag your questions properly. [tag:french] is meaningless (all questions on this site are about French). [tag:france] is for French as spoken in France as opposed to other countries, which this question is not about.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, I will reverse the direction of the translation :

- The first sentence :

  > The university courses will start **in three weeks**

  becomes

  > Les cours à l'université vont commencer **dans trois semaines**

  so, within 21 days.
- The second sentence :

  > The university courses will start **in week three**

  becomes

  > les cours à l'université vont commencer **à la troisième semaine**

  That's "correct" but case-specific : indeed there is a lack of information here, since we do not know which month or year it is about (third week of which month)... Thus the speaker has to precise a landmark starting from which we start counting weeks.

A more convenient sentence would be :

> Les cours à l'université vont commencer **à la troisieme semaine du mois prochain**.

I hope this clears up the ambiguity.

Finally, in French or in English it's not convenient (although correct) to reference order by number such as in "week three" : we should rather use "third week"/"troisième semaine".

Answer (score 1):

It means that the university courses will start in three weeks.