# Does “eux” stand for “them” or for “they”?

Tags: pronoms

I came about the French word "eux". I'm a bit confused of the proper usage of the word. Is it "them" or "they", or do the usages not correspond? When is *eux* used in French?

Comment: it is a "tonic pronoun," which English doesn't have. Think of it as the English word "them," but heavily emphasized. If you are just looking to translate to English, you can safely say "them." However, not all instances of English "them" correspond to French "Eux." This link may help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#Disjunctive_pronouns

Comment: Please tag your question properly. The tag [*france*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france) is for French as spoken in France as opposed to other countries, which this question is not about. Quoting what [@Gilles told you a few days ago](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/what-does-this-sentence-mean).

Comment: When you ask about the meaning of a word, please quote the sentence where you have met the word. Please take time to read the [Help center](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask?).

Comment: Another [helpful link](http://www.learnfrenchathome.com/grammaire_pronoms.htm) to learn about French pronouns.

Answer (score 4):

French language is always tricky, so I'll say, both and more :)

If "Eux" is used as a subject, it's they. Ex: "Je voulais venir, mais eux ne voulaient pas" => "I wanted to come, but they didn't".

If it is used to induce a possession, it's their. Ex: "Je vais chez eux" => "I'm going to their house"

Finally, you can also find it used as an object, and then it's them. Ex : "Tu les as vus?" => "Have you seen them?"

Comment: je pense qu'il faut dire "je voulais venir, mais eux, ils ne voulaient pas..."

Comment: Il manquait une virgule en effet, mais je ne suis pas sûr qu'il soit obligatoire de rajouter un sujet supplémentaire, à moins de vouloir ajouter une redondance.

Comment: Les deux sont possibles, mais sans la répétition du sujet il n'y a pas de deuxième virgule : "Je voulais venir, mais eux ne voulaient pas".

Comment: Au temps pour moi je ré-edit! Merci de l'info

Comment: Ce n'est pas *eux* qui introduit la possession mais *chez* dans cette phrase. *Eux* does not induce possession, in this sentence *chez* does.

Comment: @hunter: à la rigueur, mais encore très lourd. « Je voulais venir, eux pas », « Je voulais venir, eux non » ou « je voulais venir, pas eux »

Comment: Translating to English is certainly not a way to explain the use of *eux*.