# Les pronoms toniques utilisés comme sujets

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-personnels, sujet

Dans une réponse a la question [Does “eux” stand for “them” or for “they”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/is-it-them-or-they) j'ai appris qu'on peut dire :

> Je voulais venir, mais eux ne voulaient pas.

Qu'est-ce que c'est la règle pour l'utilisation des pronoms toniques en tant que pronoms sujets ? Si on échange les rôles de la première personne et la troisième personne, dans la phrase, peut-on dire  « ... mais moi voulais » ? Ça me semble épouvantable !

Ce qui me dérange, c'est ça:

> Eux voulaient venir, mais moi, je ne voulais pas

le « je » n'est pas optionnel, mais c'est obligatoire. On ne peut pas utiliser un verbe conjugué directement après « moi ». Donc on peut pas dire

> Eux voulaient venir, mais moi ne voulais pas **(interdit)**

Mais à ma connaissance, la seule différence entre cette phrase et celle au dessus, c'est que j'ai échangé les rôles des premières et troisièmes personnes.

Comment: C'est épouvantable en effet... Je substituerais cette phrase par *Ils voulaient venir, mais moi non.* ou *Ils voulaient venir, mais moi, je ne voulais pas venir.*

Comment: Question similaire : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/lui-peut-%c3%aatre-sujet-mais-pas-moi

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez j'ai laissé une « bounty » dans votre question parce que je voudrais une référence canonique, ça veut dire je voudrais savoir si un linguiste ou autre savant a jamais étudié cette phénomène... mes références (bien très basiques pour les apprenants) ne le mentionnent pas.

Comment: J'ai complété ma réponse en fonction de ta question que tu avait pas mal modifiée. En espérant que ça répond au moins partiellement à ton attente. L'étude de la langue n'est pas une science exacte !

Comment: @Laure je te remercie comme toujours pour la réponse avec des références... malheureusement c'est l'autre question (celle de Stéphane Gimenez) à laquelle j'ai attaché un « bounty »... donc si tu en as envie, tu doives y prendre ta réponse.

Comment: La question de @StéphaneGimenez est différente de celle que tu avais posée. Il part de l’a priori (faux) que *moi* ne peut pas être sujet. Ta question remaniée - si j'ai bien compris - est de savoir pourquoi moi et toi dans certains cas ne sont pas employés seuls (sans redondance avec le pronom comme sujet atones). Il pose en effet la question dans un commentaire et je lui ai signalé ma réponse ici. (Les bonus c'est pas mon problème, merci)

Comment: @Laure: Moi pense que ma question est très bien posée et ne part d'aucun a priori faux.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tu demandais pourquoi « Lui » peut être sujet, mais pas « moi » ? Moi, est sujet. Le titre était mal formulé. le titre de la question de Hunter plus général permet une réponse plus large. même si le déroulé de sa question a évolué au fil des questions que ma réponse lui a suscité. En fait les deux questions et les réponses sont maintenant complémentaires. mais j'ai signalé ma réponse et les gens pourront passer de l'un à l'autre !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En effet les pronoms personnels toniques peuvent être sujets.

- Pour insister sur le sujet :

  > Moi, je passe d'abord.
  >   Je le sais bien, moi.
- Pour marquer une opposition entre deux sujets :

  > Je suis française, mon frère, lui, est belge.
  >   Je voulais venir, mais eux ne voulaient pas.
  >   Je voulais venir, mais lui ne voulait pas.
  >   Ils voulaient venir, mais moi je ne voulais pas.

  Dans cet exemple, comme tu l'as justement remarqué, « moi » tout seul ne se dit pas.
- Dans des propositions où le verbe n'est pas exprimé :

  > — Qui est d'accord ?  — Moi
  >   Il est content, moi aussi.
  >   Il est plus grand que toi.
  >   Je suis d'accord, mais eux non.
  >   Je voulais venir, eux non.
  >   Ils voulaient venir,  moi non.

  Dans ce cas on ne peut pas mettre le pronom personnel sujet atone (je, tu, ...)
- Dans le cas où deux sujets sont coordonnés :

  > Mon frère et moi avons regardé la finale.
  >   Ni lui, ni moi n'avons touché au gâteau.
- Après le présentatif *c'est*, *ce sont* :

  > C'est lui qui a fini le gâteau.
  >   Ce sont eux qui sont partis en dernier.
- Avec *aussi* et *non plus*.

  > — J'ai faim. — Moi aussi.
  >   — Je n'ai pas envie de sortir. — Moi non plus.
- Quand le pronom sujet est suivi d'un mot qui le renforce :

  > Elle seule a le droit d'y toucher.
  >   Lui-même me l'a dit.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse, vous êtes toujours tellement approfondie. Mais je suis encore un peu perdu. Je pense que je comprendre vos catégories, mais il me semble que l'exemple donné n'apparaît pas dans la liste. Et c'est vrai, ce que Sifu a dit dans le « comment », que l'on ne peut pas échanger les rôles de moi et eux dans cette phrase ? (Par exemple, « **Ils voulaient venir, mais moi voulais pas », qui est parallèle, c'est interdit, non ?)

Comment: @hunter J'ai ajouté tes exemples sous la "bonne catégorie", est-ce que c'est plus clair ? Il est possible que j'ai oublié des cas, c'est difficile de faire une synthèse comme ça.

Comment: @hunter Ils voulaient venir, mais moi je ne voulais pas

Comment: merci de tes messages. Ce que me dérange encore c'est que ce n'est pas parallèle. Après moi, on a besoin d'utiliser « je ». Mais après eux, on n'a pas besoin d'utiliser « ils ». C'est ce dernière chose qui est tellement nouvelle a moi.

Comment: On peut presque considérer que ces pronoms constituent une forme une forme de vocatif.